# I want add allow notification permission prompt in flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, notifications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJu8T.png)
I want to ask the user this type of promt in both the android and ios ,when the user come inside my app. But im not able to achive it.
So if some one know please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide info, what you have already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [permision_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package like this:

```
Future<void> requestNotificationPermissions() async {
   final PermissionStatus status = await Permission.notification.request();
   if (status.isGranted) {
      // Notification permissions granted
   } else if (status.isDenied) {
      // Notification permissions denied
   } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      // Notification permissions permanently denied, open app settings
      await openAppSettings();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. But I tried this it giving a status means permission denied or not . But I want the default pop up. Will it come or I need to create custom pop up

Comment: are you using android 13?

Comment: no im using android version 8

Answer (score 0):

i think it is related to Native Android Stuff
you have to add this permission to your Mainfest.xml

In this dialog, users have the following actions available to them:

- Select allow
- Select don't allow
- Swipe away from the dialog, without pressing either button

check this topic:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission